# AHK script doesn't replicate what manual keystrokes do

Tags: autohotkey

When I perform the following keystrokes manually:

`Ctrl+Alt+Home`
followed immediately by `Alt+Tab`

...it does [exactly what I want](https://superuser.com/questions/567725/how-do-you-leave-windows-remote-desktop-connection-with-keyboard-shortcut): inside my RDP session, it minimizes my RDP session and lands me back on my actual PC. So I built the following autohotkey script which should do the exact same thing:

```
; CTRL+F12 to execute

^F12::
Send, ^!{Home} ; Press Ctrl+Alt+Home
Sleep 200
Send, !{Tab} ; Press Alt+Tab
return
```

But it does almost nothing. As in, when I have notepad open and active (as an example), when I execute the AHK by pressing `CTRL+F12`, notepad minimizes but nothing else happens. I remain inside my RDP session.

Note: When inside an RDP session, `Ctrl+Alt+Home` reveals the RDP session bar at the top, which I have set to be hidden by default. Then `Alt+Tab` hides my RDP session altogether, landing me back on my PC.

This works every time when done manually. What am I doing wrong in my AHK script?

Comment: The sleep is in Milliseconds and I guess that's too less a time for the top bar to show up. Your second set of keys are passed earlier than required and thus this issue. Try increasing the sleep duration to 2000 and that should probably help.

Comment: Roy, that didn't help - identical results as before. In fact the RDP bar at top never even displays.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, try one of the [Send variants](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Send.htm), like [`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Send.htm#SendInputDetail):

> SendInput is generally the preferred method to send keystrokes and mouse clicks because of its superior speed and reliability

Also, try for testing to increase the sleep duration.
And see if the [`SetKeyDelay`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/SetKeyDelay.htm) could interfere:

```
^F12::
SetKeyDelay, 0
SendInput, ^!{Home} ; Press Ctrl+Alt+Home
Sleep 500
SendInput, !{Tab} ; Press Alt+Tab
return
```

---

If that change nothing (as [this thread](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=107135) seems to confirm), try and use [Windows Spy](https://amourspirit.github.io/AutoHotkey-Snippit/WindowSpy.html) to get the class of the RDP Windows, and send events to it:

```
^F12::
SetControlDelay -1
ControlSend,, ^!{Home}, ahk_class TscShellContainerClass
Sleep 200
ControlSend,, !{Tab}, ahk_class TscShellContainerClass
return
```

Or try the [Windows On-Screen Keyboard (OSK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/iot-enterprise/os-features/on-screen-keyboard)

```
^F12::
Run, osk ; open On-Screen Keyboard
Sleep 200
ControlClick, Button5, ahk_class OSKMainClass ; simulate Ctrl
Sleep 100
ControlClick, Button7, ahk_class OSKMainClass ; simulate Alt
Sleep 100
ControlClick, Button15, ahk_class OSKMainClass ; simulate Home
Sleep 200
ControlClick, Button6, ahk_class OSKMainClass ; simulate Alt
Sleep 100
ControlClick, Button9, ahk_class OSKMainClass ; simulate Tab
Sleep 200
Process, Close, osk.exe ; close On-Screen Keyboard
return
```

Do replace `ahk_class TscShellContainerClass` with the actual class of the window you are targeting.

Comment: Sorry VonC but that made no difference. Still does nothing. I wonder if the fact that I'm inside an RDP session when I run this makes AHK behave differently for some reason.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder OK, then maybe try and send event to the RDP Window itself? I have edited the answer with some suggestions.

Comment: I tried your next 2 approaches and neither worked. I'm very unclear how to obtain "the actual class of the window I'm targeting".

Comment: @HerrimanCoder I meant the class of the Remote Desktop Connection window, the one in which your RDP session runs. Use the Spy tool included with AHK (as mentioned [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=13138)) to get the [`ahk_class`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_class), discusses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45642727/6309).

Comment: Von, I used spy and confirmed that the classname is (as you stated) TscShellContainerClass. Still, your AHK script using that class does nothing. I suspect it's because, within RDP (which is where my AHK script runs) it's unaware of that window. I would have to be outside my RDP session, on my host machine, for AHK to find that window by that class name -- but that doesn't do me much good.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder Yes, the point of my alternative approach is to trigger that from outside the RDP session, since no script seems to work well from inside the RDP session.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately running the script from outside does me no good.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder I understand. I proposed it as an alternative since it does not seem possible to run a AHK script from the inside of an RDP session.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect it to work? Running AHK inside the RDP session means AHK can only interact with elements within the session such as the virtual keyboard and mouse, while the RDP session bar (and its hotkey) are managed by your local machine and outside of anything AHK works with.

Try writing the AHK script on your local machine, outside the RDP session, and use it to launch that session, and set it up so the local machine traps the hotkey (not so easy, but try using the caps-lock for part of it since caps-lock impacts the keyboard locally).

I have a thread discussing this issue but for an AWS WorkSpace but it might reveal some help: [Any way to toggle between local desktop and AWS Workspace in full screen view using code or a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747838/any-way-to-toggle-between-local-desktop-and-aws-workspace-in-full-screen-view-us)

Comment: PGilm, I have to run it inside the RDP session; that's the whole point. When I'm inside my RDP session and I press `CTRL+ALT+HOME` on my keyboard, the RDP connection bar displays at the top, which is what I want. Why shouldn't it work when AHK presses those same keys for me?

Comment: Because you are executing the keys on your machine (inside the scope of your RDP window). How do you expect it to execute the command outside of your RDP when being run inside? That would be a major security flaw (e.g. someone triggering the exact keystrokes to e.g. obtain remote access to your device (escaping RDP window, opening CMD, etc...) - which of  course isn't possible)! @HerrimanCoder

Comment: OK, same with Ctrl Alt Delete -- somethings are inherently trapped at the local level.  That's one advantage of running AHK outside the RD but for an inside method, try including in your AHK shortcut sending "Ctrl + Alt + Pause/Break". This will take you out of full screen mode and "un-trap" the keys, meaning you can now do "Alt + Space" then "n" to minimize the RDP and put you in the local desktop.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+Pause/Break also does nothing when run by AHK.

Answer (score 1):

If you could run locally the code, this should work. But minimize a RDP session from inside, probably won't be possible.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class TscShellContainerClass
^Capslock:: ; CapsLock is one of the few keys that are interpreted locally even when connected via an RDP session. Using Control+F12 probably won't work in this case.
Sleep 50
WinMinimize A
return
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Dieisson, thanks for trying, but unfortunately that did nothing.

Comment: Are you running it locally or within the RDP session? The command to execute the script is Control+Caps Lock, not Control+F12, as F12 isn't interpreted locally when an RDP session is active.

Comment: I have to run it within the RDP session - that's the whole point. And yes, I tried CTRL+CapsLock, but it did nothing.